# Send accelerometerdata from wear to mobile

Tags: android, wear-os

I am looking for the best way to send accelerometer data from my Android Wear device (20 entries per second) to my smartphone. The exchange should be as fast as possible to create a nearly real time XYchart on the smartphone.

What is the best way to send my data? Does MessageAPI provides an exchange which is fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either the Message or Data API. `SharedPreferences` aren't automatically "shared" between devices (such as a watch and a phone).

Also, be realistic about data transfer rates. You'll get accelerometer data on the watch at a **much** faster rate than you can realistically send it to the phone, and will need to handle that discrepancy. It might be that you want to use the Channel API instead - but that will require repackaging your `ArrayList` into a `Stream`.

Comment: Okay I see the problem. By now Ive limited the Sensor data to 20 records per second. And maybe I will evaluate the data directly on the Smartwatch. Do you have any experience which rate could be possibly sended in appropriate time?

Comment: I don't have that specific experience, no. It would probably depend on how strong the Bluetooth signal is, what else is using the link, and other factors. You'd need to run your own tests to determine what rate works for you.